# Use FFmpeg library in Swift

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, rtsp

I wanted to use FFMPEG library for RTSP live streaming and broadcasting . I downloaded FFMPEG libraries and and included in bridging header ,but gives error

> "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_av_register_all",
>   referenced from:"

How do I use FFMPEG library in swift? Can I use FFPlay to play the live video in iOS App?

Comment: did you get these ffmpeg libraries? https://github.com/chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

- libiconv.tbd
- libbz2.tbd
- libz.tbd

To your **Build Phases -> Link Binary With Library**

This is what solved the problem for me.